# Is a backend language necessary for the github api?

Tags: javascript, api, github-api

Do I need a backend language(i.e. Ruby)for the Github API, or can I make curl requests with just javascript.

Comment: *"curl requests with just javascript"* JavaScript has `curl`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use front-end JavaScript.

> [The API supports Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) for AJAX requests from any origin.](https://developer.github.com/v3/#cross-origin-resource-sharing)

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this

Answer (score 0):

**Nope**. You can just use simple JavaScript or you can curl it as it is.

To **curl** it on the terminal:

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/users/Evin1-/repos
```

Or... a **JavaScript function** to communicate with the API (same data as the previous curl function):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    request.open("GET", 'https://api.github.com/users/Evin1-/repos');
    request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            console.log(request);
            var p_placeholder = document.getElementById("result_placeholder");
            p_placeholder.innerHTML = request.response;
        }
    };
    request.send(null);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="result_placeholder"></p>
</body>
</html>
```